# Are there any state of the art crypanalysis tools for stream cipher

Tags: cryptanalysis, stream-cipher

I am new to cryptanalysis and interested in knowing cryptanalysis tools (black boxing or white boxing) for (not any specific) stream ciphers in general sense.

Scenario: I am given an assignment to evaluate a stream cipher which is implementing techniques like NLFSR and LFSR etc.